# How to implement MyClass<T extends OtherClass> in C++?

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics, extends

can someone tell me how to implement this Java-Code in C++?

```
  public class MyClass<T extends OtherClass>{
    ....
  }
```

I've tested this in C++:

```
 template<class T, class OtherClass>
 class MyClass
 {
    public:
          MyClass();
  }
```

But I've get the error:`invalid use of template-name 'MyClass' without an argument list`

Greetings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) in combination with `static_assert`:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
    static_assert( std::is_base_of< OtherClass, T >::value, "T does not extend OtherClass");

public:
    MyClass();
};
```

(you can, of course, also make `OtherClass` an additional template parameter in case you need to be more flexible)

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a templated class (ie what you did with `template<class T, class OtherClass>`) then you must use the templates you declare. Since you did not use `T` or `OtherClass` in `MyClass` you get the compiler error.

As for how to implement `T extends OtherClass` in C++, its not as simple because C++ has multiple inheritance, but you can use the `is_base_of` function in `stl`

Comment: The first part is plain wrong. You don't get a compile error just because you don't use a template parameter, this is perfectly legal and there are even some use-cases for that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in C++ you would just use:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
```

You don't need to say anything like `extends OtherClass`.

Here's the explanation:

In both C++ and Java, when you access a method or field of an object, the compiler must make sure that the static type of the object expression supports that method or field, or it will fail to compile.

In Java, generic classes and methods are compiled only once. When a generic class or method is compiled, it is unknown what type parameters (like `T`) are or could be. Therefore, bounds are necessary to make the compiler allow accessing methods and fields that are not provided by `Object`. The reason for having the bound `T extends OtherClass` is because somewhere in `MyClass`, it tries to access a method or field on an expression of type `T`, which is provided by `OtherClass`. Thus this bound allows the compiler to type-check and successfully compile.

In contrast, in C++, templated classes and methods are compiled once for each different type argument (called each "instantiation" of the template), as if the compiler copies and pastes a copy of the template code and substitutes the actual type argument for each occurrence of `T` in the code. Therefore, when a templated class or method is compiled, it is known exactly what type `T` is. A specification of a bound, like in Java, is unnecessary, because the compiler can directly check whether the type that `T` is supports a given method or field. If `T` is a subtype of `OtherClass`, it will successfully compile. If `T` is not a subtype of `OtherClass`, chances are that it will not have a method or field of that name, and even if it did, it may not have the right type for it, so it will likely fail to compile. It is basically duck-typing.

(It is unlikely, but possible, that you have a different, unrelated type that is not a subtype of `OtherClass`, that also has methods and fields of the same name and type as the ones in `OtherClass` that are used in `MyClass`, and if you try to parameterize `MyClass` with that type, the compiler won't complain about it. However, it is probably bad design for such a type to exist anyway, and it is unlikely you will accidentally use such a type in the wrong place.)